# Index to Multi-Index Column Header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set 1 one of index's to a column header, so that there would be multi-index on the columns and 1 index along the rows.  In my example, I want "Name" to be the index along the rows with "Period" and "Grades" as the multi-index in the columns.  When "Period" shifts into the column index, the row index "Name" should become unique.

Here is my sample df:

```
Name = pd.Series(['John','Sarah','Paul','John','Sarah','Paul','John','Sarah','Paul'])
Period = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
Grades = pd.Series(['A','C','D','B','A','C','F','B','A'])

dfs = (pd.DataFrame({'Name':Name,'Grades':Grades,'Period':Period}))
dfs = dfs.set_index(['Name','Period'])
```

I would like for it look like this:

[image]

Comment: `dfs.unstack('Period').swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)`?